# Using setTimout to execute a function written in arrow syntax gives me an error

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I execute this code I receive an error: Cannot access 'bye' before initialization

```html
setTimeout(bye, 3000);

console.log('Hello');

let bye = () => console.log('Goodbye');
```

But if I change the function to regular function syntax, it executes as I would expect it to. Why is this happening, and is there a way to make this work with arrow syntax?

Comment: declare your `bye` function before calling it in the `setTimeout`

Comment: Because you are using bye before intializing, use **var bye = ...** instead of **let** or use timeout after the arrow function

Comment: Thank you! Someone just mentioned hoisting as well, so now I have some good documentation to read over

Answer (score 2):

It's called Hoisting, arrow functions don't allow for it so you have to declare them before calling them.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

Comment: Thank you Andre! This makes so much sense now